# OAuth2 - Authenticate a web api (therefore without any frontend) which is at the same time a "client"

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, .net-6.0, webapi

I'm implementing a simple OAuth2 server using .NET 6, and I would like to understand if there is a way to authorize a Web Api project with protected endpoints but at the same time authenticate itself from the OAuth2 server on startup.

So there is no type of frontend, so there isn't insertion of credentials by a physical user.

I would like to understand if it is possible to authenticate the web api without having a third party client application between the webapi and the OAuth server. And if yes what is the best auth flow to implement for this case?

Comment: See cookie settings in following example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-identity-services

Answer (score 1):

This is what the client credentials grant type was built for.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4

There is no user, the client "authorizes itself" by authenticating as the client previously arranged to allow access.

The diagram here is quite useful in visualizing.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4

Comment: actually, it's true that in the rfc-editor the scheme is client to server, but then in the documentation where it'd implemented I always see that there are three applications: the web api, the client, and the oauth server. Should I therefore use this flow by integrating the "client" part directly into the web API?

Comment: I see. If you want to use OAuth, then there'll be at min. those 3. Have a look here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1 at the roles. The web API is the resource server, the client is the OAuth client, and the OAuth server is OAuth authorization server. When you request authorization, it's for using the api

Comment: But, the flow to get a token in the client credentials grant type only involves the client and the authorization server. The next step to use the token brings in the web api

Answer (score 1):

For most of time, you need a "login window" to input the username and password, then get the access token.
If without a "login window" , you should already have an user credential in your codes. There is a flow called "Resource owner password credential" may meet your needs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#authorization-request

Comment: Those are only if a user needs to authenticate which isn't how the question is written. Also, you should NOT use the resource owner password credentials grant type https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics#name-resource-owner-password-cre